# Create a "claim" environment

Tags: environments

I am writing a quite long proof in a LaTeX file and I would like to create a "claim" environment to put inside said proof. Can someone help me to understand how this can be done, or at least redirect me to some manual or other resource where it is explained?

What I would like precisely is two environments:

claim: similar to theorem, but maybe instead of getting **Claim** (bold), only underlined.

claimproof: similar to the proof environment, but with a black box at the end, to distinguish its end from the end of the full proof of the theorem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have a look at the `amsthm`, `ntheorem`, and perhaps `thmtools` packages to help you with this :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Requires `amssymb` for the black square.

```
\newenvironment{claim}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Claim:}\space#1}{}
\newenvironment{claimproof}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{Proof:}\space#1}{\hfill $\blacksquare$}
```

You can edit and use `Claim's proof` for example, or anything else. Also, adjust the space above and below, if you want.

```
\begin{claim}
foo
\end{claim}

\begin{claimproof}
foo
\end{claimproof}
```

[image]

**ps:** Following the suggestion by @barbara beeton, to avoid new lines before the black square, replace the last pair of `{}` by

```
{\leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\quad\hbox{$\blacksquare$}}
```

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud, you're welcome. Try to improve the code using some other commands for spaces above and below, like theorems does. Now you have the starting point.

Comment: this definition could leave the black box at the beginning of a line by itself, if you're unlucky enough to have the text of the claim end at the end of a line.  better to steal the code from `amsthm`:  `\leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\quad\hbox{$\blacksquare$}`

Comment: How could I imagine this?! Nice! I'll edit and cite your code.

Comment: @Sigur How can I use the same environment, but with enumeration, i.e. to keep track of Claim 1, Claim 2, and so on?