# Question about numbered claims

Tags: numbering, lyx, theorems

My claims starts with something like:
"Claim 0.1"
How do I change the numbering? Maybe to something like "Claim 1".

Comment: you are not giving any information but presumably you are doing something like use `\section` without using `\chapter` so the solution would be to use a class without chapters, or use `\chapter` as your top level sectioning command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your question doesn't give us anything like the information we need to help you.  Please prepare a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to help us help you.

Comment: Is `Claim` a theorem-like structure?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104098/create-a-claim-environment

Comment: Presumably you've added the *Theorems Numbered by Section* module (if you're using the standard article class) or *Theorems numbered by Chapter* (if you're using a book or report class). Hence, deleting that module will likely help. (You must have added some modules anyway, as Claim is not available by default.)

Comment: @API Obviously not, that is about creating a claim environment from scratch, while this question is about modifying the numbering of an existing environment *in LyX*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Claim` environment forms part of a "Theorems" module. It can be numbered in a variety of ways. Most likely you have it set to be "Numbered by Chapter" (or perhaps "Numbered by Section"):

[image]

Delete that selection, which will remove the subordinate numbering.