# How to Make Claims and Proofs start on the same page if possible?

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, proof-package

I have a document where sometimes proofs start on a separate page than where their associated claims were stated.

Is it possible to force is so that (unless the statement of the claim is more than one page) the proof will always start on the page where the claim was stated?

Example:

[image]

```
LaTeX Code:

%% LyX 2.2.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[oneside,english,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}[section]
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem{claim}[thm]{\protect\claimname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beraserif}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{berasans}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1,small,euler-digits]{eulervm}
%\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
% make boxes around proofs:
%-------------------
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\surroundwithmdframed[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  bottomline=true,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=\dimexpr\topsep+6pt\relax,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{proof}
%-------------------

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemii{\(\circ\)}
  \def\labelitemiv{\(\star\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
  \providecommand{\claimname}{Claim}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. 
\begin{claim}
This is a claim.
\begin{proof}
This is the associated proof. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hbar & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar\\
 & = & \hbar
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the theorem and the proof in a `minipage` should provide them on the same page, but not necessarily on the one you want to have them ;-)

Comment: If you know how much space is needed for the theorem and the start of the proof, you can use the needspace package.  BTW, \rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-5\baselineskip} is a better way to fill up a page.

Comment: is this helpful ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104098/create-a-claim-environment

Comment: @EladDen, I guess this line: {\leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\quad\hbox{$\blacksquare$}} is where it's at but I am not sure exactly how to implement it in my situation.

Comment: I am sorry, the link was not helpful, @ChristianHupfer is, however...

Comment: The question is ill-posed. TeX *will* start in the same page *if possible*

Comment: @egreg, the question was meant to ask how to make sure that priority is given to "place claims and proofs on the same page" above "save space". As you can see in the example picture I posted, TeX prioritizes saving space, which ends up producing counter-intuitive output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `needspace` (but I don't know in the least how you can do this with LyX).

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{needspace}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{claimINNER}[thm]{\protect\claimname}
\newenvironment{claim}
 {\par\Needspace{2\baselineskip}\claimINNER}
 {\endclaimINNER}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beraserif}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{berasans}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1,small,euler-digits]{eulervm}
%\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
% make boxes around proofs:
%-------------------
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\surroundwithmdframed[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  bottomline=true,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=\dimexpr\topsep+6pt\relax,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{proof}
%-------------------

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemii{\(\circ\)}
  \def\labelitemiv{\(\star\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
  \providecommand{\claimname}{Claim}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.

A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.

A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.

A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.

A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text
goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot
of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here.
A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes
here. A lot of text goes here. A lot of text goes here. 
\begin{claim}
This is a claim.
\begin{proof}
This is the associated proof. 
\begin{align*}
A & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B \\
  & = B 
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in @Christian Hupfer's comment.

You  mentioned using lyx, so you need to add ERT before your claim starting a minipage.

```
\begin{minipage}[]{1 \textwidth}
```

and an ERT after your proof closing the minipage:

```
\end{minipage}
```

Make sure your ERT is always in "standard" environment.

For more information about minipage and it's use look it up in ctan, or take a look [at this website](http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-minipage.html)

Another way is using `samepage`: add ERT before claim with

```
\begin{samepage}
```

And after proof close with

```
\end{samepage}
```

As @Christian Hupfer said the `minipage` might not put the claim and the proof where you want it, changing the options within the minipage `[...]` or using `samepage` might solve your placing problem

[image]